# Create prefunded accounts on a test blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, wallets, testrpc

I want to create a test blockchain to play around.
When I try test-rpc there are already ten accounts created but no funds - how can I generate funds? can I import a genesis.json?

My second approach is to use

```
geth init '/my-path/genesis.json'
```

I generated some accounts with https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ and added some funds with alloc in genesis.json:

```
{
  "config": {
        "chainId": 0,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
  "alloc": {
  "0xFf0333b3Cfa24652646eA24fe98a54f0f1001849": {"balance": "111111111"},
  "0xFEfaf15eEc2D3F06958043acA3aF3766745358aB": {"balance": "111111111"},
  "0xFf0333b3Cfa24652646eA24fe98a54f0f1001849": {"balance": "78111111111"},
  "0xb0A7C9Fa07Be78cBf2F3a5b1A87Cd87BBA72A1Ed": {"balance": "977111111111"},
  "0x4eD82D45102cB38cf8c7b4261675b2FEB577063e": {"balance": "324111111111"},
  "0x46347159a3497d3AC1948D44294268C1E3a3A321": {"balance": "2345234111111111"},
  "0x8a58Cc8EeACeFA52f6f70C4F116F57291438F2dB": {"balance": "224111111111"},
  "0x1a4Ec59De4d833e06dfA1700E8611D4B3a4B4EBd": {"balance": "2424111111111"},
  "0x124BC9eBd0447F5e594F871691415a212A5EcA63": {"balance": "2222244222222222"}
},
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x2fefd8",
  "nonce"      : "0x000005678000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

The problem is I need to add this accounts with private keys manually to the geth "wallet".
What would be a good automatic solution for wallet creation within geth so I can immediately start to move ether around on my new test environment?

Comment: probably you can craete accounts in advance using `geth --datadir "your_directory" account new`

Answer (score 4):

You can create the accounts using geth before you init the chain with the genesis block.

`geth --datadir <DATADIR> account new`

The keystores are stored to `<DATADIR>/keystore`

You would:

1. create the accounts
2. add the accounts to genesis.json
3. init/start blockchain

If you need to restart the blockchain from scratch, you can keep the keystore folder in your `<DATADIR>`, so you don't have to recreate the account again.